# How to automatically resize and centre tkinter window

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I have an issues with window resizing in tkinter when a user variable is displayed. As the program takes in the name of a team and display's it later in the program, having a set size for the display window will not work as it needs to be adaptive. I have got code for centring the window, but is there a way to automatically set the size of the window?

Current Look:

```
team_2 = t2_entry.get()
        top_2.withdraw()
        confirm_screen = Toplevel(master)
        w = 160 + len(team_2) + len(team_1)
        h = 50
        ws = confirm_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = confirm_screen.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
        confirm_screen.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        t1_name = Label(confirm_screen, text = "Team 1: " + team_1).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        t2_name = Label(confirm_screen, text="Team 2: " + team_2).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        confirm_button = Button(confirm_screen, text = "Submit", width = 10, command = team_name_1).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        redo = Button(confirm_screen, text="Redo", width=10, command= lambda: [start_team1(), clear()]).grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Attempts 1:

```
team_2 = t2_entry.get()
        top_2.withdraw()
        confirm_screen = Toplevel(master)
        w = 160 + len(team_2) + len(team_1) 
        h = 50
        ws = confirm_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = confirm_screen.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
        confirm_screen.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        t1_name = Label(confirm_screen, text = "Team 1: " + team_1).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        t2_name = Label(confirm_screen, text="Team 2: " + team_2).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        confirm_button = Button(confirm_screen, text = "Submit", width = 10, command = team_name_1).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        redo = Button(confirm_screen, text="Redo", width=10, command= lambda: [start_team1(), clear()]).grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Attempt 2:

```
team_2 = t2_entry.get()
        top_2.withdraw()
        confirm_screen = Toplevel(master)
        w = confirm_screen.winfo_width
        h = confirm_screen.winfo_height
        ws = confirm_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = confirm_screen.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
        y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)
        confirm_screen.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        t1_name = Label(confirm_screen, text = "Team 1: " + team_1).grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        t2_name = Label(confirm_screen, text="Team 2: " + team_2).grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        confirm_button = Button(confirm_screen, text = "Submit", width = 10, command = team_name_1).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
        redo = Button(confirm_screen, text="Redo", width=10, command= lambda: [start_team1(), clear()]).grid(row=4, column=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```py
from tkinter import *

confirm_screen = Tk()
t1_name = Label(confirm_screen, text = "Team 1: " + "team_1").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
t2_name = Label(confirm_screen, text="Team 2: " + "team_2").grid(row = 1, column = 2)
confirm_button = Button(confirm_screen, text = "Submit", width = 10, command = None).grid(row = 4, column = 1)
redo = Button(confirm_screen, text="Redo", width=10, command= lambda: [start_team1(), clear()]).grid(row=4, column=2)

# You need to update the display so that the widgets are actually displayed on the screen.
# Otherwise `w` and `h` will both = 1
confirm_screen.update()

w = confirm_screen.winfo_width()
h = confirm_screen.winfo_height()
ws = confirm_screen.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = confirm_screen.winfo_screenheight()
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)

confirm_screen.geometry('+%d+%d' % (x, y))
```

You have to first place all of the widgets and then calculate where the window should go. Also there is no need to always include the size of the window when using `<tkinter.Tk>.geometry(...)`.

Comment: That does work in the sense of resizing the window, but it appears to be off centre, and more on the bottom right of the screen. I'll keep at it and try to find a way to postion it. If I do, ill edit the your comment and mark it as answer

Comment: @EamonSharma I think I fixed it, you need a `confirm_screen.update()` before you calculate the position (it allows the widgets to display themselves then calculates the size of the window).